# переход с apache на nginx+php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, чпу, php5-fpm

Пытаюсь перейти на nginx+php-fpm с apache.
 
Сайт работает, но не работает ЧПУ. Конкретно не получается переписать одно правило из `htaccess`.
Конфигурация сайта `joomla 3.9 + nginx 1.17 + php5-fpm + mariadb`. 
Работает в контейнерах docker. 
Не могу переписать правило созданное для apache модуля `mode_revrite` из файла .htaccess 
Перевожу через онлайн конвертер (https://winginx.com/ru/htaccess), но где-то ошибка и страница не грузится, а выходит загрузка файла.
Вот правило из .htaccess (рабочее)

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]|.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC] RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Из конвертера получается правило

```
location / { rewrite /component/|(/[^.]*|.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ /index.php break; }
```

Кто разбирается может подсказать где ошибка в правиле для nginx?

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите свой вопрос в нормальном виде, а не одной строкой.

Comment: лучше весь конфиг покажите. уж явно проблема не в одной строке.

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка файла может происходить из-за того, что сам php5-fpm подключен неверно.

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/tmp/fpm-file1.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include     fastcgi_params;
    }
```

есть что-то такое в конфиге? пути к сокету верные? сокет есть в файловой системе?

Comment: Без данного правила все  работает. Сайт открывается, но не работают ссылки ЧПУ, правила которых прописаны в .htaccess были.

Comment: Настройки php5-fpm
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        # fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}

Comment: Это правило:

        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
         }

Запустило ЧПУ что были?

Comment: fastcgi_pass php:9000; - php в этой строке у вас точно правильная переменная? ассоциируется ли с ней какой-то ip адрес?

Comment: да, это host c контейнером docker, pph работает если не втыкать данное правило, только именно с конвертированным rewrite выходит проблема

Comment: пробовал так  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  и так 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

ссылки ведут на главную после их включения.

Comment: что пишут логи php/nginx ? возможно там есть что-то указывающее где опечатка или ошибка?

Comment: нет ничего в логах необычного. Сервер отдает код 200 при переходе по ссылке по которой идет загрузка страницы